# Assigning a value to the global variable (and a argument of a function aswell) R

Tags: r, global-variables, global

I am currently working on my master thesis (model of a evolutionary trust game). And I have a following problem. I have several types of investors and trustees that are paired to play the trust game. Investors and trustees are defined as vectors. What I would like my code(trust game) to do is that it takes the (globally defined) investor and trustee. They play together the iteration of the trust game and then the globally defined variables are updated inside the function trust game. I would like that it would work for any investor\trustee that is used as the argument of the function trustgame. Do you know how could I code this? I am not sure aswell if it will help you but I post my code aswell.

```
    #### defining trustees ####
# [1] honor\abuse
# [2] information about previous interaction - relevant to investors who buy the information
# [3] payoff
# [4] number of interactions
trustee1 <- c(1,0,0,0)
#### defining investors ####
# [1] buy\not buy
# [2-4] investment decision if buying information in case 1(TH), case 2(TA), case 3(NT)
# [5] aggregated payoff
# [6] number of interactions in one generation
investor1 <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0)


here is the code for the trust game

trustgame <- function(investor,trustee)
{ investordecision <- NULL
trusteedecision <- trustee[1]
investor[6] <- investor[6]+1
trustee[4] <- trustee[4]+1
if (investor[1]==0) investordecision <- investor[2]
if (investor[1]==1)
{ if (trustee[2]==1) investordecision <- investor[2]
if (trustee[2]==2) investordecision <- investor[3]
if (trustee[2]==3) investordecision <- investor[4]
if (trustee[2]==0) investordecision <- rbinom(1,1,0.5)
}
if (investordecision==1 && trustee[2]==1) trustee[2] <- 1
if (investordecision==1 && trustee[2]==0) trustee[2] <- 2  
if (investordecision==0) trustee[2] <- 3

if (investordecision==1 && trusteedecision==1)
{trustee[3] <- trustee[3] +3
investor[5] <- investor[5] + 3 }
if (investordecision==1 && trusteedecision==0)
{trustee[3] <- trustee[3] +5
investor[5] <- investor[5] + 0 }
if (investordecision==0 && trusteedecision==0)
{trustee[3] <- trustee[3] +1
investor[5] <- investor[5] + 1 }
if (investordecision==0 && trusteedecision==1)
{trustee[3] <- trustee[3] +1
investor[5] <- investor[5] + 1 }

}
```

Comment: `<<-` will modify a global variable inside a function. Be careful.

Comment: I know but I have several types of both trustees(trustee1,trustee2,...) and investors(investor1,investor2,...) and I would like to perform these changes automatically to ones that are currently used as an argument of the function since I will be doing large simulation afterwards and I don't want to type everything manually.

Comment: `get` and `assign` with the `envir` argument? Once you start with heavy usage of `<<-`, `get` and `assign`, it's a good indication things are going wrong.

Comment: My basic question was whether something like this is possible to do in R. I could return a list cointaining the updated trustee and investor vector but I would prefer to update the firstly defined variables as I have stated. Thanks for help though

Comment: Yes, not only is it possible, I think I've given you three functions to use to make it happen. I'm not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the functions

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs are strings, you can use `get` and `assign` to change the values in the global environment like this:

```
trustee1 <- c(1,0,0,0)
investor1 <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0)

trustgame <- function(investor_string,trustee_string){ 
  investor <- get(investor_string, envir = globalenv())
  trustee <- get(trustee_string, envir = globalenv())
  investordecision <- NULL
  trusteedecision <- trustee[1]
  investor[6] <- investor[6]+1
  trustee[4] <- trustee[4]+1
  if (investor[1]==0) investordecision <- investor[2]
  if (investor[1]==1){ 
    if (trustee[2]==1) investordecision <- investor[2]
    if (trustee[2]==2) investordecision <- investor[3]
    if (trustee[2]==3) investordecision <- investor[4]
    if (trustee[2]==0) investordecision <- rbinom(1,1,0.5)
  }
  if (investordecision==1 && trustee[2]==1) trustee[2] <- 1
  if (investordecision==1 && trustee[2]==0) trustee[2] <- 2  
  if (investordecision==0) trustee[2] <- 3

  if (investordecision==1 && trusteedecision==1){
    trustee[3] <- trustee[3] +3
    investor[5] <- investor[5] + 3 
  }
  if (investordecision==1 && trusteedecision==0){
    trustee[3] <- trustee[3] +5
    investor[5] <- investor[5] + 0 
  }
  if (investordecision==0 && trusteedecision==0){
    trustee[3] <- trustee[3] +1
    investor[5] <- investor[5] + 1 
  }
  if (investordecision==0 && trusteedecision==1){
    trustee[3] <- trustee[3] +1
    investor[5] <- investor[5] + 1 
  }
  assign(trustee_string, trustee, envir = globalenv())
  assign(investor_string, investor, envir = globalenv())
}

trustgame("investor1", "trustee1")
> investor1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
> trustee1
[1] 1 3 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me a big time :)

Comment: I have one more question. Since I want to do a simulation of the evolution of the population of investors meeting with the trustees I had to store the population of the investors in the list. Im struggling to make the function trustgame work for the elements (vectors) of the list in which the population is stored. Could you please give me a hint how to deal with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: @hed0r I modified it to use investors and trustees in a list... https://gist.github.com/corynissen/5526748a7f839a207335cc1db2dd8931